# Consolidate javascript timeout functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the basic level of the question, but js definitely isn't my area of expertise. However, it's one of those questions that's difficult to Google an answer on.

I basically want to do a couple of things when the window is resized. I have a little bit of extra code that also stops the resize event firing twice.

The issue is that I'm duplicating bits of code, that as a coder, I know is wrong. The problem is I don't know how to go about making it right. Here's my current duplicated code:

Event binding

```
    $(window).on("resize", resizeText);
    $(window).on("resize", resizeIndicator);
```

Functions

```
function resizeIndicator() {
    clearTimeout(id);
    id = setTimeout(updateIndicator, 200);
}

function resizeText() {
    clearTimeout(id);
    id = setTimeout(updateText, 200);
}
```

Thse are not duplicated but included for completeness:

```
function updateIndicator() {
    $tab = $(".tabs li.focus");

    if ($tab.length) {
        toggleIndicator($tab, true);
    }
}

function updateText() {
    $tabs = $(".tabs li:not(.indicator) a");

    $tabs.each(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("two-line", this.scrollWidth > $(this).outerWidth());
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not calling one function on resize and do what you want to do on resize? Have you tried something like that?

Comment: You are using ths same global "id" in both resize methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your timeout id globally and use single handler.

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/nugutujoli/1/edit?js,console,output

```
$(window).on("resize", resizeEvent);

var timeout;
function resizeEvent() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      updateIndicator();
      updateText();
    }, 200);
}


function updateIndicator() {
   console.log("update indicator fired.");
}

function updateText() {
    console.log("update text fired.");
}
```

Comment: This does not fix problem of code duplication at all.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to avoid code duplication? No problem use higher order of function to create new function.

```js
function createResizeCallback(resizeFunc) {
  var id;
  
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(id);
    id = setTimeout(resizeFunc, 200);
  }
}


$(window).on("resize", createResizeCallback(updateText));
$(window).on("resize", createResizeCallback(updateIndicator));


function updateIndicator() {
    console.log('updateIndicator');
}

function updateText() {
    console.log('updateText');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I forgot to add return. Fixed it, should be fine now.

Comment: This code is an improvement but still has some duplication on the bindings.

Comment: @JohnOhara Well, I assumed that you wanted to add event listener for some reason. Otherwise I saw no reason why would you do that in such strange way, because other answer to this question is quite obvious.